# Can I display some KML on a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Is it possible to have some KML hardcoded into some Html page and have google maps display that hardcoded KML to a google map?

Right now, I keep seeing documentation that requires the KML to be located somewhere else -> an HTTP endpoint on some webserver (which is not what I want).

Any ideas?

Comment: unless you could have a self-referring HTML/KML file, I don't see how this is possible :(

Answer (score 5):

The [geoxml3 KML parser](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) will parse a KML string embedded in your page and display it on the map (as native Google Maps API v3 objects, not a KmlLayer, that does require a publicly available KML file).